# Best way to separate PHP and Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a best way to separate javascript and php code. for example:

```
//php code
if(condition1)
{
    ?>
    // javascript code
    $card_typej = $(this).val().trim();
    if(condition2)
    {
        $("#id1").html('<?php echo($var1); ?>');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#id1").html('<?php echo($var2); ?>');
    }
    <?php
}
?>
```

If yes then, how to separate the above code?

Comment: First of all, don't prefix JS variables with `$`. That'll only lead to confusion.

Comment: @Ankur Tiwari: there is no "best way". you just need to make sure everything works as expected and the errors are handled correctly. and, of course, to make sure is easily readable by you or another coder that might need to modify your code. also, you can search for examples over the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First store required PHP variables in Javascript vars and then manipulate it.

```
<script>
var var2 = <?php echo json_encode($var2); ?>;
var var1 = <?php echo json_encode($var1); ?>;
if(condition1)
{
    ?>
    // javascript code
    $card_typej = $(this).val().trim();
    if(condition2)
    {
        $("#id1").html(var1);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#id1").html(var2);
    }
    <?php
}
?>
</script>
```

You can see, complicated php+js code mixture is not there now.

Comment: You should use `<?php echo json_encode($var2); ?>` to ensure that the variable has correct JS syntax.

Comment: @AnkurTiwari welcome :) And by the way your twitter is not working